# parse xml using dom java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the bellow xml:

```
<modelingOutput>
    <listOfTopics>
        <topic id="1">
            <token id="354">wish</token>
        </topic>
    </listOfTopics>
    <rankedDocs>
        <topic id="1">
            <documents>
                <document id="1" numWords="0"/>
                <document id="2" numWords="1"/>
                <document id="3" numWords="2"/>
            </documents>
        </topic>
    </rankedDocs>
    <listOfDocs>
        <documents>
            <document id="1">
                <topic id="1" percentage="4.790644689978203%"/>
                <topic id="2" percentage="11.427632949428334%"/>
                <topic id="3" percentage="17.86913349249596%"/>
            </document>
        </documents>
    </listOfDocs>
</modelingOutput>
```

Ι Want to parse this xml file and get the **topic id** and **percentage** from ***ListofDocs***

The first way is to get all document element  from xml and then I check if  grandfather node is ListofDocs.
But the element document exist in **rankedDocs** and in **listOfDocs**, so I have a very large list.

So I wonder if exist better solution to parse this xml avoiding if statement?

**My code:**

```
public void parse(){
    Document dom = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

    dom = db.parse(is);

    Element doc = dom.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList documentnl = doc.getElementsByTagName("document");
    for (int i = 1; i <= documentnl.getLength(); i++) {
        Node item = documentnl.item(i);
        Node parentNode = item.getParentNode();
        Node grandpNode = parentNode.getParentNode();
        if(grandpNode.getNodeName() == "listOfDocs"{
            //get value
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when checking the node name you shouldn't compare `String`s using `==`. Always use the `equals` method instead.

You can use XPath to evaluate only the document `topic` elements under `listOfDocs`:

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("//listOfDocs//document/topic");

NodeList topicnl = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for(int i = 0; i < topicnl.getLength(); i++) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use the if statement you can use XPath to get the element you need directly.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("source.xml");
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/*/listOfDocs/documents/document/topic");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id"));
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("percentage"));
}
```

Please check GitHub project [here](https://github.com/plopcas/st-parse-xml).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It happens to be basically the same solution as the one proposed by manouti, only a little bit more detailed. Probably working on it at the same time. I will leave it here for reference just in case you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org) for such tasks:

```
public class Answer {

    @XBDocURL("resource://data.xml")
    public interface DataProjection {

        public interface Topic {
            @XBRead("./@id")
            int getID();

            @XBRead("./@percentage")
            String getPercentage();
        }

        @XBRead("/modelingOutput/listOfDocs//document/topic")
        List<Topic> getTopics();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final DataProjection dataProjection = new XBProjector().io().fromURLAnnotation(DataProjection.class);
        for (Topic topic : dataProjection.getTopics()) {
            System.out.println(topic.getID() + ": " + topic.getPercentage());
        }
    }
}
```

There is even a convenient way to convert the percentage to `float` or `double`. Tell me if you like to have an example.