# Get element by text content - XML, Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

There are **org.w3c.dom.Document** methods such as `getElementById(String elementId)`, `getElementsByTagName(String tagname)` etc., but is it possible to get elements by their text value?

Comment: nope. I think you will have to create your own utility.

Comment: thanks, I've been searching for such a utility hoping that someone had already created it but I haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with the plain DOM API. You can use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) which can be easily integrated with DOM. For example, the following XPath expression would return all `Element` nodes having text content `abc`:

```
//Element[text()="abc"]
```

You can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556878/parse-xml-using-dom-java/26557041#26557041) for an example.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try using some [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).

within your JS, use the element.innerHTML to compare the text/value of the element.